# Class not found exception while loading the applet(org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: can't instantiate default ORB implementation)

Tags: java, swing, applet, classnotfoundexception

I have a applet which usually uses jacorb.jar in endorsed directory under jre .Now I made a change in code to download jacorb.jar tp the windows temp folder (eg. C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\endorsed) .Using the jre installed in our local along with jars downloaded from the webpage we used to launch to the applet from different clients.  But while launching the applet i receive the below error

```
org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: can't instantiate default ORB implementation org.jacorb.orb.ORB  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.create_impl(Unknown Source)
at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(Unknown Source)
at com.nm.util.OrbUtils.initAppletORB(OrbUtils.java:2)
at com.nm.ani.share.aniclient.AniClient.initializeORB(AniClient.java:2)
at com.nm.ani.share.aniclient.AniClient.initializeCorba(AniClient.java:33)
at com.nm.ani.share.aniclient.AniClient.initialize(AniClient.java:19)
at com.nm.ani.share.aniclient.AniClient.<init>(AniClient.java:10)
at com.nm.ani.clients.lib.ui.windows.CampusApplet.createA(CampusApplet.java:66)
at com.nm.ani.clients.lib.ui.windows.CampusApplet.getA(CampusApplet.java:68)
at com.nm.ani.clients.campus.main.CampusMain.performAniLogin(CampusMain.java:30)
at com.nm.ani.clients.campus.main.CampusMain.initia(CampusMain.java:6)
at com.nm.ani.clients.lib.ui.windows.CampusApplet.init(CampusApplet.java:17)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jacorb.orb.ORB
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source
```

Later i found that applet is searching for jacorb files in endorsed directory itself . It is not using the jar file in windows temp directory in which jars downloaded from the webpage newly.

I have changed every possible code to point to temp directory but it is not happening

please guide me on this...

Comment: *"Due to some requirements we are made to shift the location"*  What requirements?  Be specific. *"to windows temp folder."*  How it that supposed to work?  Is the applet in a web page that is being *served* from that same machine?  If not, it could never work..

Comment: How it that supposed to work? The applet is launched from web application and it downloads three jars to the client(our machine) one among them is jacorb.jar. then using corba connection , it connects to the server and launches the applet along with jre installed in our local machine.  Sorry I am a newbie to this, pardon me if i am not clear

Comment: @ Andrew Requirement: Now jars are getting downloaded to endorsed directory under jre from web application and i am trying to change the download location to windows temp directory (which i have completed ) and launch the applet using jars downloaded in temp directory . To connect to server corba comes into existence . Machine where my web-application runs is in my intranet